# Django Tastypie Secret Key

Tags: django, tastypie

I am currently building a simple django app to serve basic models to an Android client. I'm using Tastypie as webservice, and I would like (well.. I need to) to implement a minimal security process as follow :

Hardcode the secret key in the Android app. Done.

Request via http GET the data I want, with the secret key as parameter. Done

Make the tastypie check this key in the requests made to django by the android app. ?..

I guess it is a fairly easy thing to do but I'm currently learning Django / Python etc and I haven't figured out what to make of the tastypie docs on this particular topic :

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html

FYI, I'd rather not have this key user-generated for the simple reason I did not understand how it would work. Tastypie says it can generate an api key upon user creation, but what then ? How does the app get this key ?

Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you look at [django middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/). I'm assuming you're passing the key through in the request (I'd do it in the request header). The middleware should simply check for the existance of this key, and if it exists, let the request through, otherwise return a 403.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm going to look into that as you suggest it, have a nice day :-)